# Upper bound of $\left(e^{-a + \frac{a^2(B+2)}{2} - \frac{1}{2}\left(a - \frac{a^2(B+2)}{2}\right)^2} e^ {a (1-\epsilon)}\right)^k$

Tags: real-analysis, upper-lower-bounds

I am reading a paper which states

$$ \underbrace{\left(\left( 1 -a + \frac{a^2}{2} (B+2) \right) e^ {a (1-\epsilon)}\right)^k}_{(i)} \leq \underbrace{\left(e^{-a + \frac{a^2(B+2)}{2} - \frac{1}{2}\left(a - \frac{a^2(B+2)}{2}\right)^2} e^ {a (1-\epsilon)}\right)^k}_{(ii)} \\ \leq \underbrace{e^{-\frac{(\epsilon^2-\epsilon^3)k}{2(B+1)}}}_{(iii)}, \tag{1}$$
with $B \geq 1$. It is stated that $(i) \to (ii)$ can be done by using $e^{-x + x^2/2} \geq 0$ for $x \geq 0$. Supposing that this is correct I am trying to prove $(ii) \to (iii)$.

In the description says that the upper bound $(iii)$ can be obtained by using $a = \epsilon/ (B+1)$ in $(ii)$ by noting $B \geq 1$.

The first think I have tried so far is to rewrite $(1)$

$$\left(e^{\frac{a^2(B+2)}{2} - \frac{1}{2}\left(a - \frac{a^2(B+2)}{2}\right)^2} e^ {-a\epsilon}\right)^k \leq e^{-\frac{(\epsilon^2-\epsilon^3)k}{2(B+1)} }\tag{2}$$ hopping to use the result [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4620999/why-1-epsilonk-2-exp-epsilonk-2-exp-left-frack2-epsil). The next thing I thought was that the value $a = \epsilon/ (B+1)$ mentioned in the paper is a some root that give a tighter bound. So I have decided to define

$$x(a) = \frac{a^2(B+2)}{2} - \frac{1}{2}\left(a - \frac{a^2(B+2)}{2}\right)^2\tag{3}$$ and
$$f(a) = e^{x(a)}\tag{4}$$ with goal to find the optimal $a$ that minimize $f(a)$ in order to get a tighter bound on $(ii)$. In this direction we need to compute $a$ that satisfies $\partial_a f(a) = 0$, i.e.,

$$\partial_a f(a) = f(a) \partial_a x(a) = 0\tag{5}$$
which using $f(a) > 0$ equals

$$\partial_a x(a) = 0\tag{6}$$ or more specifically

$$\partial_a x(a) = a\left(-\frac{1}{2} (B+2)^2 a^2 + \frac{3}{2} (B+2) a + (B+1)\right) = 0.\tag{7}$$

It seems that the determinant of $(7)$ does not lead in something useful related to $a = \epsilon / (B+1)$. Could you please someone cast some light? Any help is highly appreciated.

<sup>The inequality is from the end of the proof of Theorem 1 in the paper "An algorithmic theory of learning: Robust concepts and random projection".</sup>

Comment: it's probably simpler - that stuff with $x(a)$ is increasing w.r.t $B$, so they probably just did $B+2 \ to B+1$ and subistituted.

Comment: @dezdichado thanks for the interest. Probably I need some more help in order to reach the result. Can you please provide a detailed answer to see how it is  exactly computed?

Comment: Any suggestions please to reproduce the upper bound?